# Transform rows to comma delimited string by groups of n records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on this sample table

| ID | NAME | ZIP | NTID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | 123 | H1 |
| 1 | Juan | 123 | H2 |
| 2 | John | 456 | H3 |
| 2 | John | 456 | H4 |
| 2 | John | 456 | H5 |

I want to show `ntid` as a comma separated value but in groups of maximum 2 items

Expected result

| ID | NAME | ZIP | NTID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | 123 | H1, H2 |
| 2 | John | 456 | H3, H4 |
| 2 | John | 456 | H5 |

Using SQL Server, is there a way to achieve this?

By using the `STRING_AGG` function it concatenates all in a single row, but I need to group as groups of maximum of 2 members.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ZIP, STRING_AGG(NTID,',')
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, NAME, ZIP
```

Comment: Hint:  `STRING_AGG()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That function will concat all the items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can use a modified row number (divided by 2) to group your data into blocks of 2 rows, and then you can use `string_agg()`.

You do need a way to order the rows though (if you want consistent results), I have assumed `NTID` will work, but you may have a better column to order by.

```
declare @Test table (ID int, [NAME] varchar(32), ZIP varchar(12), NTID varchar(2));

insert into @Test (ID, [NAME], ZIP, NTID)
values
(1, 'Juan', '123', 'H1'),
(1, 'Juan', '123', 'H2'),
(2, 'John', '456', 'H3'),
(2, 'John', '456', 'H4'),
(2, 'John', '456', 'H5');

with cte as (
    select *
      , (row_number() over (partition by ID order by NTID) - 1) / 2 rn
    from @Test
)
select ID, [NAME], string_agg(NTID,',')
from cte
group by ID, [NAME], rn;
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ffd2852c25ae5ac163ff834038b8b1d)

Note: If you supply the DDL+DML as part of your question you make it much easier to answer.